# How can I make my code more efficient for Roman to Integer conversion?

Tags: python, performance, runtime

I'm new to programming. In Python, I wrote a program to convert Roman numerals to integers. The constraints are:

```
1 <= s.length <= 15
s contains only the characters ('I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M').
It is guaranteed that s is a valid roman numeral in the range [1, 3999].
```

How can I make this run faster?

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        intList = []
        for i in s:
            if i == 'I':
                intList.append(1)
            elif i == 'V':
                intList.append(5)
            elif i == 'X':
                intList.append(10)
            elif i == 'L':
                intList.append(50)
            elif i == 'C':
                intList.append(100)
            elif i == 'D':
                intList.append(500)
            elif i == 'M':
                intList.append(1000)
        
        sum = 0
        skip = True
        for number in range(len(intList)):
            if (number < len(intList) - 1) and (intList[number] < intList[number + 1]):
                sum += intList[number + 1] - intList[number]
                skip = False
            elif (not skip):
                skip = True
                continue
            else:
                sum += intList[number]
                
        return sum
```

Comment: It's easier to see the program running step-by-step in https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot to understand your code!

Answer (score 3):

Will approach this by using *dictionary* like this;
Just compare and do the right ops. Except the last one, if one letter is less than its latter one, this letter is subtracted.

```py
 def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        ans = 0
        prev = 0
        dc = {'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000}
        
        for c in s[::-1]:
            v = dc[c]           # based on @Stuart suggestion
            if prev > v:
                ans -= v
            else:
                ans += v
                prev = v
        return ans

# check it out.... using these "XII" "XXVII" "MMXX"
```

Comment: This is very good but can be improved by *v = dc[c]* immediately inside the *for* loop then use that instead of continually looking up in the dictionary. I timed it. It really does improve matters

Answer (score 0):

## try to call this method by passing the roman string

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
    ref_obj = {
'I': 1,
'V': 5,
'X': 10,
'L': 50,
'C': 100,
'D': 500,
'M': 1000,
'IV': 4,
'IX': 9,
'XL': 40,
'XC': 90,
'CD': 400,
'CM': 900
}
    total = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if i + 1 < len(s) and ref_obj[s[i]] < ref_obj[s[i + 1]]:
            total = total + ref_obj[s[i] + s[i + 1]]
            i = i + 2
        else:
            total = total + ref_obj[s[i]]
            i = i + 1
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

@FunPROG : i don't have a `python` solution handy but you can adapt the high-level approach -

if u wanna make it more efficient, don't use loops at all ::

```
 1  8 VIII
 2  54 LIV
 3  65 LXV
 4  90 XC
 5  1999 MCMXCIX
 6  2000 MM
 7  2022 MMXXII
 8  3000 MMM
 9  3499 MMMCDXCIX

10         # gawk profile, created Fri Nov  4 15:27:43 2022
11         # Rule(s)
12       9  ($++NF=_____($! _))^_ { # 9
13       9     print
14         }
15         # Functions, listed alphabetically

16      9 function _____(____,_,___,__)
17        {
18      9   return sprintf("%.*s", int((____+=_=_<_)/(___=(_+=++_)+_^++_)^_),
                     "MMM" ) 

             substr("CDCCCM",
20              ((__=int(____/___^--_)%___)%(___/=_))==_^_ \
                ? ___^(_^-(_=-_)<__) : _+(_=__<___), _<-_ ? -_ : __%___+!_)

             substr("XLXXXC",
22              ((__=int(____/(___+=___))%___)%(___/=(_+=_^=_<_)))==_^_\
23              ? ___^(_^-(_=-_)<__) : _+(_=__<___), _<-_ ? -_ : __%___+!_)

24           substr("IVIIIX",
                ((__=____%(___+___))%___)==(_+=_^=_<_)^_\
25              ? ___^(_^-(_=-_)<__) : _+(_=__<___), _<-_ ? -_ : __%___+!_)
26        }
```